# Lower bound using Largest Singular Value of Pseudo-Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, vector-spaces, regression

For uni I've got this exercise where i need to prove the following:

$$\sigma_{max}(X^\dagger)^2 \ ||Xw-Xw^* ||_2^2 \geq ||w - w^* ||_2^2$$

where $\sigma_{max}(A) = max_{u \in \mathbb{R}^d \ ||u||_2 = 1} ||Au||_2$ is the largest singular value for matrix $A$, and $X^\dagger$ is the pseudo-inverse of matrix $X$.

I've tried just writing out the left hand side, but this did not help me any further. Does anyone know how I could tackle this problem? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It may help to use the sub-multiplicativity of the 2 norm: $\Vert A B \Vert_2 \le \Vert A \Vert_2 \Vert B \Vert_2$ for matrices $A$ and $B$ of conformable dimensions

Comment: This is false. E.g. when $w-w^\ast$ is a nonzero vector in $\ker(X)$, the LHS of the inequality is zero but the RHS is positive.

Comment: @user1551 you're right, apologies. It is also given in the exercise that $w, w^* \in range(X^T)$, does this make a difference?